# How do NFT marketplaces work in terms of issuing tokens?

Tags: tokens, nft

I'm trying to understand how NFT marketplace work on a high level, in order to be able to build my own.

Speaking of an average NFT marketplace:

(1) Do NFT marketplaces usually mints **its own** tokens? And all its users (participants), therefore, use those tokens in all the operations on a marketplace: mint, buy, sell?

(2) Or is it that users (participants) bring their own tokens from **outside, minted or bought elsewhere,** and then buy, sell those on a marketplace?

(3) Or is it a hybrid between the (1) and (2)? And it depends on a particular marketplace?